# optional argument breaks multicolumn

Tags: macros, optional-arguments

If you are using a command to append a multiline to a tabular, it will stop working if the command has optional arguments. It will work without them:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\newcommand{\mwe}[2][1]{ % remove [1]
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{text}
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{ll}
        \mwe[1]{1} % [1]->{1}
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

(Minimal working example, works when changed according to comments)

Error:

> `Misplaced \omit`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What should the optional argument do in that example?

Comment: I wanted to use the command to append a Quote to the table (+other normal table stuff)
If it would be too long for one row, i wanted to use the optional argument to be able to split the Quote over 2 lines. Like

------------------
"this is a short Quote"
1      2        3
------------------
"This Quote is too
 long for one row"
1      2        3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a known problem: `\multicolumn` has to be the first object in a cell (after expanding macros), but the command with optional argument places something before it.

Use `xparse`.

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\mwe}{O{1}m}{%
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{text}%
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{ll}
        \mwe[1]{1} % [1]->{1}
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

So long as the list of arguments ends with `m` (a mandatory argument), the command is fully expandable.